# Is it possible to use Juju without having sudo access on local machine?

Tags: juju

I would like to be able to use juju on a shared remote machine (ie: nitrous.io or c9.io). Is that possible?  And if so, how would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to using the juju client commands (IE, `juju deploy`, `juju bootstrap`, etc) None of those commands require sudo at the moment. The new "local" provider for juju will require sudo power, but that's only if you're doing a local LXC deployment.

On the remote side of things, the juju-agent does require and run as root.

I'm not entirely sure how either part of juju would fit in to the shared machine model of c9.io or nitrous.io (Are you going to have those IDEs drive Juju?). If you're looking for integration points with those services, the juju client is set up in such a way that you can do that (have a unique `$JUJU_HOME` for each user where they can maintain their own `environments.yaml`, etc). I haven't attempted integration personally but it there shouldn't be too much to change in order to do so.

If you're trying to deploy services to a shared machine as a regular user that likely will not work.

Comment: Ok, it was easy after I found this README: https://github.com/prabhakhar/juju-core . I just wanted the client tools and was able to get that working following the instructions in that README.

Comment: I'm not sure who that is, but you'll likely want the official github mirror: https://github.com/juju/juju-core or the lp project: http://launchpad.net/juju-core

Comment: Ahh, didn't know there was an official mirror, thanks. Launchpad is way too confusing, even if you can find the README (which is hard enough), it's hard to read.

Comment: That mirror is refreshed every few hours, so it's not a one-to-one sync, but if you like github then http://github.com/juju and http://github.com/charms are the accounts to follow!